# How to combine two uneven Observables in Rxjava?

Tags: rx-java

I am having two different Observables, one a Observable of Map and another a Observable of list each containing uneven records. How can I combine the two Observables to update the Map by taking the value from the list?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `zip` can combine two Observables items together.

Comment: How do you want to key into the map? Could you write an ordinary example, (i.e., no Observables) that does what you want ?